# Space at end of line in CSV when merging multiple CSVs

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, merge, space

I wrote a batch to merge multiple CSVs from current directory into one taking into account that my CSVs have a header. But the file I get contains a space character at the end of each line.

```
@echo off

pushd %~dp0

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set cnt=1

for %%i in (*.csv) do (
    if !cnt!==1 (
        for /f "delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> merged.csv
    ) else if %%i NEQ merged.csv (
        for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> merged.csv
    )
    set /a cnt+=1
    echo !cnt!
)
```

Comment: because you explicitly write it: `echo %%j >> merged.csv`. To avoid the space `(echo %%j)>>merged.csv`

Comment: Another way might be `echo %%j>>"merged.csv"`.

Comment: I tried with `(echo %%j) >> merged.csv` and it worked so the important here is to delimit the echo with ().

Comment: the important thing is not to write the space. The parentheses are just one possible way. @lit's comment may give issues, when `%%j` ends with a digit. Another possible solution: >>merged.csv echo %%j`

Comment: How about `echo>>"merged.csv" %%j`?

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan commented, you explicitly tell it to add a space, but as another option maybe this will be a shorter version?

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
for %%i in (*.csv) do if "%%i" NEQ "merged.csv" type "%%i" | more +1 >> merged.csv
```

Comment: Will the resulting `merged.csv` have a header record?

Comment: @lit I am assuming the header should be removed from in general.

Answer (score 0):

- This batch will leave the header in only the 1st csv
- If you use a var as a flag and just check if it exists you don't need delayedexpansion.
- You also need to exclude `merged.csv` from being appended (to itself).

---

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
set "flag="
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B *.csv ^|find /v "merged.csv" ') do (
    if not defined flag (
        copy "%%i" merged.csv
        set flag=anything
    ) else more +1 "%%i" >>merged.csv
)
popd
```